# Структура данных "2 массива в одном"

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм, любой-язык, структуры-данных

Как реализовать/как нызывается структура данных (контейнер), которая может быстро выполнять следующие операции?

1. итерация по всем элементам 1 контейнера;
2. итерация по всем элементам 2 контейнера;
3. итерации по элементам контейнера из элементов 1, а потом 2 (без проверок на каждой итерации, надо ли переходить в следующий контейнер)
4. вставка (можно в конец)/удаление по указателю; могут быть отложенными, т.е. смысл в том, чтобы они были/их не было на следующей итерации по элементам, необязательно сразу вставлять/удалять.

Идея в том, чтобы хранить 2 массива в 1, чтобы быстро итерироваться как по отдельности, так и по 2 сразу, при этом иметь возможность вставлять и удалять из обоих. Произвольный доступ не нужен.

Как вариант думаю о списке, растущем одновременно влево и вправо для 2 контейнеров, но проблема в том что итерация будет медленной из-за нелокальности данных = кеша.

Если можно, то реализация на C++/Python, но достаточно алгоритма.

Comment: 2 обычных списка в Питоне. Комбинированный итератор - простой генератор из двух последовательных циклов по спискам с yield внутри.

Answer (score 0):

это просто массив с номером границы:

```py
n = [1,2,3,4,5]
g = 2
for i in range(0,g):
    #n[i] - элемент 1 контейнера
for i in range(g,len(n)):
    #n[i] - элемент 2 контейнера
for i in range(0,len(n)):
    #n[i] - элемент контейнера
del n[i]# 1 контейнер
del n[i+g]# 2 контейнер
s = n[i:]
del n[i:]
s = a + s
g += 1
n += s# 1 контейнер
s = n[i+g:]
del n[i+g:]
s = a + s
g += 1
n += s# 2 контейнер
```